# rspec with dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I would like to include some dynamic data in my test output.

if I write a test like this then it prints out "it should have '' things"

I figure I'm getting confused with rspec's magic and ruby's blocks as closures.

I can stick at count in a method outside the block but that seems hack-ish.

Any pointers?

```
describe 'things' do
  before :all do
    @count = 3
  end

  it "should have #{@count} things" do
    #....
    page.should have_content("entries: #{@count}")
  end


end
```

if I write a test like the above then it prints out "it should have '' things"

Edit:
Another, more specific example

```
describe 'things' do
  before :all do
    @thing = FactoryGirl.create(:thing)
  end

  it "should display a thing with name #{@thing.name} " do
    #....
    page.should have_css("h1", text: @thing.name)
  end


end
```

Comment: I think it's unclear what exactly is being asked here. If the "@count" is part of some other object that is also under test, than your test names need to indicate that this is the case -- as in "the page entries should be equal to the (object-name.count)". To set this fresh before each it statement use before each, not before all.

Comment: I added a more specific example.  Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your guidance.

Comment: In this case, I would probably, as recommended by @JeremyPatterson use let(:thing){FactoryGirl.create("thing")}, and not have the actual value in my test name... rather, say it "should display the name of the FactoryGirl". Having the explicit value in the test name actually reduces comprehension--its much more important *where* the value is coming from than what the value is.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables don't work in the **it** method, but constants do.  I like to namespace it according to the **describe** block.

```
describe 'things' do
  THINGS_COUNT = 3

  it "should have #{THINGS_COUNT} things" do
    #....
    page.should have_content("entries: #{THINGS_COUNT}")
  end
end
```

**Edit**: Using a constant ensures you can't change the value.

**Edit 2**: Dynamic variables should be something more generic, by no means should active record objects be used.

A common pattern I've used *dynamic variables* are for similar tests with different input/output.

```
[ 
  [1, true],
  [2, false],
  [3, true]
].each do |number, result|
  it "should return #{result} for #{number}" do
    number.odd?.should == result
  end
 end
```

In this case you can DRY up your tests and it's easier to test different variations.

It's better to use `let(:person) { Factory.create(:person) }` or `before(:each)` for specific active record objects.

Comment: Never do that)) it just like using global vars, u r poluting global var space

Comment: Agreed, that's why I've added a namespace to it. However, the global var space is not worth it.   It's better not to use a constant, I never realized that you could do it without it.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov **Always** do this. Constants exist for a reason: so that you can create references to immutable values. If you want to test against the value of an integer, you want that integer to be immutable. If you -1'd this answer, I'd reconsider.

Comment: the issue with this is that the variable in question could be an active record object and would be cleaned out of the database  after the first 'it'

Comment: If the variable in question is an active record object and may be cleaned out of the database, then you are asking a completely different question than the one you appear to be asking. You appear to be asking "How can I give an integer a name", which is being answered. :before_each and :before_all allow you to create objects that you can use inside your tests--just not in the NAMES of your tests. If your test compares two active record objects, rather than some object attribute/method return to a preset value, then those *names* should be in the name of your test, not the value itself.

Comment: yes, I realize my hasty efforts to simplify  my scenario in fact lead to skewing the question out of context.  My apologizes and thanks for all your input.

Answer (score -1):

```
it "should have #{@count} things" do
```

evaluates before you define instance variable, so it will be `nil`.

You can however define the variable outside the `before` block and it will work.

```
describe 'things' do
  count = 3

  it "should have #{count} things" do
    #....
    page.should have_content("entries: #{count}")
  end

end
```

***Edit:*** you have access to top level vars in blocks.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe a way to pass a variable to the it method.

Comment: Unless you're entering text on a phone with an actual nine letter keypad, I would recommend using 'you' instead of 'u'. This isn't an instant message. Also, you mean 'to top', not 'too top'.

Comment: Nice, this way avoids defining multiple constants.

Comment: @JeremyPeterson I'm not sure why you would want to avoid multiple constants. If you use a variable, and you ever change the value (which would be the only reason to use a variable rather than a constant) then you will introduce dependencies between your tests, which is a genuinely terrible idea. For this use, constants are the *far* better choice.